# TDengine "show tables like" usage

Tags: database, tdengine

I was trying the "show tables like" function described in the TDengine doc to filter out tables using pattern matches. I have multiple tables like tb_1, tb_2 ... in the database. As described in the manual each '_' matches one character so expecting "show tables like tb__" should generate the output with all tables have "tb_x" name patterns. However the output is empty. Is this command broken or the usage is incorrect in my case?

```
    taos> show tables;
    table_name | created_time | columns | stable_name | uid | tid | vgId |
    ==========================================================================================================================================================
    tb_1 | 2021-08-25 10:58:14.668 | 4 | st | 562950003757616 | 3 | 2 |
    tb_2 | 2021-08-25 10:58:14.687 | 4 | st | 562950020535164 | 4 | 2 |
    ...
    ...
    ...
    Query OK, 100 row(s) in set (0.007341s)

    taos> show tables like tb__;              
    Query OK, 0 row(s) in set (0.005915s)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select tbname from stable_name where tename like "tb__";
```